# change backend header options

Tags: options, settings-api, design

Wordpress is offering backend pages for header and background under the design tab, which can be activated inside functions.php.

Is it possible to customize that options? For example I would like to have the possibility to choose a logo.

Or would it be a better idea to not alter that pages and integrate the custom header/background options into my theme's options tabs instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I seen lot of Templates using custom theme panels. Giving you separate page into your theme settings will make it easy to find the all the customizations inside one page.

Therefore I will go for a custom panel.